# Removing stop words in R

Tags: r, text, sentiment-analysis, topic-modeling

the full code is attached as a picture. an example of the data is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eoXT.png)

|doc_id|text|overall|
|------|-----|------|
|1|Singapore to Perth. Seats are comfortable for economy class. Slight recline. Decent menu - Asian or Western selection. Design of the plane is strange. The entire plane uses a small group of toilets right in the middle of the plane - never heard that many flushes in 5 hours. Good service. Will fly again in a different seat.| 8
when i run the programme, i receive an error saying "

```
> #remove stopwords
> comments = scan(file = "mystopwords.data", what = character(),sep = '\n')
Read 671 items
> comments<-tm_map(comments,removeWords,mystopwords[2:671])
`

Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"
```

i do not understand why i am facing this issue

I have tried removing the brackets, substituting the values in the square bracket to [1:671], [2:672] but to no avail. the file mystopwords.data is stored in my working directory.

Comment: Without reproducible data, it'll be very hard to understand your problem. Try to share an example data set

Comment: @Maël I would love to share the data but I do not know how to. Any tips?

Comment: You can use `dput`. You may have a big data set, so you can share only the first n rows, using `head`, so you got `dput(head(x, 10)`, and you copy paste the output here

Comment: the word count is too little for me to paste even a single line of data here @Maël

Comment: Did you load the package that contains the function `tm_map`?  `library(package_name)`

Comment: hello @Arthur i tried loading the package_name but they are telling me it does not exist

Comment: `package_name` is just a placeholder for the actual package name.

Comment: yes i have added, the rest of the tm_map works perfectly fine. only the stop words function is not working. @Arthur

Comment: you are trying to remove the stopwords that you loaded as the object `comments` from comments, instead of using `tm_map(corpus_object_goes_here, removeWords, comments[2:671])`

Comment: @phiver i have written the code as 
commnet_corpus = VCorpus(DataframeSource(txt))
comments = comments_corpus